# In Android how can I post this JSONObject to a server?

Tags: android, json, post

```
HashMap<String,String> list = new HashMap();
list.put("uid",String.valueOf(3));
list.put("longitude", "10.13");
list.put("latitude", "20.33");

JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(list);
```

The documentation is not entirely clear about what to do next. Given the server url is http://example.com/update.php and the server is able to parse the JSON object.

I am unable to use the deprecated apache HTTPClient object to post because I'm using API 23 and downgrading the API is not an option

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: read the official android volley tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple Http Client Libraries available like **Google Volley**,**Retrofit** and **LoopJ Async** . I personally prefer Volley when working with JSON format.

For posting your JSON object via Volley you do it like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest strReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        YOUR_URL, yourJsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject jObj) {
        // do these if it request was successful
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // do these if it request has errors
    }
});
```

These are some useful links for tutorial on Google Volley:

[Android working with Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

[An Introduction to Volley](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)